# the direction of a point of a topos

Tags: topos-theory, morphism

I would like to understand what is the direction of a **point of a topos**.
A point of a topos $\cal T$ in one source (2nd snippet below) is a functor preserving finite limits
and all colimits $$p^*:{\cal T}\to {\text {Set}}$$ to Set.

On wikipedia (1st snippet) it is the reverse direction: from Set to $\cal T$.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Wikipedia says, a geometric morphism is some *pair* of adjoint functors ($f^*, f_*$). In particular, the left adjoint $f^*$ goes in the direction opposite to that of the geometric morphism. So directionwise everything is consistent. Note that $f^*$ preserves colimits by adjointness and finite limits because its part of the definition of a geometric morphism.

Comment: It might also be worth noting that in the case of the topos of sheaves on a topological space, the direction $\mathcal{T} \to Set$ is the functor of taking stalks at $p$ whereas the direction $Set \to \mathcal{T}$ is the functor of forming the skyscraper sheaf at $p$.  Which could explain why some authors would in general prefer to think of the point as being the $\mathcal{T} \to Set$ portion of the geometric morphism.

Comment: This is unnecessary  complication, but where exactly was made the choice that $f^*$ goes in the direction **opposite** to that of the geometric morphism? Was it only in the place so as to be consistent with preserving all colimits, or even before in the adjointeness $(f^*,f_*)$ ?

Comment: @user122424 I think the motivation was that a map of spaces (schemes) gives a pair of adjoints on sheaves on these spaces, and the directions are like here. Interpreting sheaves on $X$ as etale maps $E \to X$, $f^*$ corresponds to pulling $E \to Y$ _back_ along $f: X \to Y.$

Comment: @DanielSchepler What the **skyscraper sheaf** means in the terms of the topos ${\text{Set}}^D$ ?

Comment: If $S$ is a set, the skyscraper sheaf of $S$ at $p$ is the sheaf whose sections over $U$ are $S$ if $p \in U$, and $1$ if $p \notin U$ - with the restriction maps being either the identity on $S$ or the unique map to 1.  (This is exactly what you get if you trace the definition of $i_* S$ where $i : \{ p \} \to X$ is the inclusion map.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Where do the restrictions maps live in ?