# cocomplete implies geometric morphism

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

How cocompleteness of a topos $\cal E$ implies that $\cal E$ is equipped with a geometric morphism $\gamma:{\cal E}\to {\text {Set}}$ ?

[image]

Comment: My guess is: maybe the pullback part of the geometric morphism (the "constant sheaf" functor) is constructed such that the constant sheaf of a (small) set $X$ is the coproduct of $|X|$ many copies of 1?

Comment: But we have agreed [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372489/the-direction-of-a-point-of-a-topos) that the geometric morphism goes **from** Set to presehave topos.

Comment: The question you linked to is talking about a point of a topos.  From the context, this paper is almost certainly talking about a geometric morphism in the opposite direction.  (In the case of a topos constructed from a topological space, $G$-torsors are related to the *constant sheaf* of $G$, not any particular skyscraper sheaf of $G$ at some point.)

Comment: Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, $G$-torsors are related to the constant sheaf: for a space $X$, there is a morphism $f^* = \Delta:  \operatorname{Set} \to \operatorname{Sh}(X) $ which sends $S$ to the constant sheaf $\Delta S.$ Its right adjoint $f_*$ is given by global sections $P \mapsto P(X).$

The book you read (Mac Lane & Moerdijk) refers to the generalization of this construction to any cocomplete topos $E$, described on p.350: the "constant sheaf" functor $f^*: \operatorname{Set} \to E$ is given by $S \mapsto \coprod\limits_{s \in S}1$ wheareas its right adjoint is now given by $P \mapsto \operatorname{Hom}_E(1, P)$ (note that this gives global sections in the case when $P$ is a sheaf). Together, these constitute a geometric morphism $E \to \operatorname{Set}.$